# Find $a,b$ such that $\lim_{x\to 2}\frac{ax+b}{x^2-4} = 1$

Tags: limits

I'm asked to find $a,b$ such that $\lim_{x\to 2}\frac{ax+b}{x^2-4} = 1$.
I do the following: 
$$\lim_{x\to 2} ax+b = (x^2 - 4)$$
$$2a + b = 0$$
$$a = 1$$
$$b=-2$$.

But this solution is not valid. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about $x^2 - 4$ as $(x + 2)(x - 2).$ To get the limit at 2 to be 1, we can do $\frac{4}{x + 2}\frac{x-2}{x-2},$ where the problematic $x-2$ terms cancel out. So the numerator should be $4x - 8.$ On the other hand, the limit of $\frac{x - 2}{x^2 - 4}$ would be $\frac{1}{4}$ rather than $1.$

Comment: okay I can accept that solution, but what step in my solution is logically wrong? Has it got to do with dividing by zero?

Comment: Yes. Having 2a + b = 0 is a necessary condition for the limit to exist, but it does not guarantee that the limit is 1 -- it could be some other number (like 1/4 in your case).

Answer (score 0):

You get $2a+b=0 $
then, $$\displaystyle\frac{ax-2a}{x^2-4}=\frac{a}{x+2}→\frac{a}{4}=1$$

finally$$a=4$$